# How can I use a predicate function parameter in the function body?

Tags: f#, predicate

I am trying to solve the 'strain' exercise on [exercism](https://exercism.org/tracks/fsharp/exercises/strain).
The function is supposed to accept a predicate function as a parameter.

```
let keep pred xs =
  function body
```

When the code is:

```
[1;2;3;4] |> Seq.keep (fun x -> x % 2 = 0)
```

How can I use the predicate in the body?

Comment: Since this is a homework question I'll avoid giving the answer directly. I suggest you look at using sequence expressions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/sequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the specific question - *how to use the predicate in the body* - let's say that we want to do something much simpler. We want to write a function that takes a predicate `pred` and a value `v` and it just returns "OK" if the predicate holds for the given value and "Nope" if it does not.

To do this, you would write:

```
let okIfHolds pred v = 
  if pred v then "OK" else "Nope"
```

To call the predicate, you just need to say `pred v`. This is the same F# function application syntax that you see when calling built-in functions like `sqrt 2.0` or `List.sum [1;2;3]` - just specify the function and its argument(s).

Comment: Hi Thomas, thank you for the response. I thought the last parameter of a function in F# is actually the output. Is that not the case? In your example code `pred` takes the predicate function and `v` is the value input but there is no parameter which sets the string output. That threw me off yesterday.